# Is it better to store a 2D image in a flat array or in an array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, image-processing, indexing, processing-efficiency, pointer-to-pointer

I have two options.

1. receiving and processing pixel data in a flat array.

If I choose it, I have to use single pointer.
I have to use this code in every repeated pixel data process.

```
int getIndex(int row, int col){
    return row*(Image_Width) + col;
}

for (int i ...){
    for (int j ...){
        R[getIndex(i,j)]
        G[getIndex(i,j)]
        B[getIndex(i,j)]
    }
}
```

2. receiving and processing pixel data in a double array.

If I choose it, I have to use a pointer-to-pointer. I don't need to use `getIndex()`.

I want to know the pros and cons of the two options and which one is efficient.

This is an example of using a single array and a double array to perform constant multiplication for each pixel data.

```
B = (unsigned char *)malloc(ImgSize);
G = (unsigned char *)malloc(ImgSize);
R = (unsigned char *)malloc(ImgSize);
for (int i = 0; i < ImgSize; i++){
    B[i] = fgetc(f);
    G[i] = fgetc(f);
    R[i] = fgetc(f);
}
for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < Width; j++){
        B[getIndex(i,j)] = int(B[getIndex(i,j)]*num);
        G[getIndex(i,j)] = int(G[getIndex(i,j)]*num);
        R[getIndex(i,j)] = int(R[getIndex(i,j)]*num);
    }
}
```

```
dB = (unsigned char **)malloc(hInfo.biHeight * sizeof(unsigned char *));
dG = (unsigned char **)malloc(hInfo.biHeight * sizeof(unsigned char *));
dR = (unsigned char **)malloc(hInfo.biHeight * sizeof(unsigned char *));
for (int i = 0 ; i < hInfo.biHeight; i++){
    *(dB+i) = (unsigned char *)malloc(hInfo.biWidth * sizeof(unsigned char));
    *(dG+i) = (unsigned char *)malloc(hInfo.biWidth * sizeof(unsigned char));
    *(dR+i) = (unsigned char *)malloc(hInfo.biWidth * sizeof(unsigned char));
}
for (int i = 0; i < hInfo.biHeight; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < hInfo.biWidth; j++){
        dB[i][j] = fgetc(f);
        dG[i][j] = fgetc(f);
        dR[i][j] = fgetc(f);
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < Width; j++){
        dB[i][j] = int(dB[i][j]*num);
        dG[i][j] = int(dG[i][j]*num);
        dR[i][j] = int(dR[i][j]*num);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the tag description that pops up when you hover your mouse over the [tag:double-pointer] tag, you'll read "The term "double pointer" is sometimes confusingly used to refer a data type which can point to another pointer. This name is confusing because it may mean a pointer to a `double` floating-point object. Please use [tag:pointer-to-pointer] instead." This is exactly the reason I was confused at first about your question, "single" and "double" usually refer to 4 and 8-bit floating-point format.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure many answers on this site and over on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) comment on this issue, but I haven't been able to find a question explicitly asking this, so I'll try to summarize pros and cons here.

In short:

1. **Array of arrays.** There are no pros here, it's all cons. At first it looks like the syntax `img[i][j]` is better than `img[i * width + j]`, but it is only superficially so.
2. **Flat array.** I cannot recommend you use anything else. This is the way to go.

Differences:

1. **Memory management.** Not only do you need a loop and `height` number of calls to `malloc` in the array of arrays, but you also need the same for freeing the memory. Memory management is much more complicated and expensive than in the flat array case.
2. **Indexing cost.** `img[i][j]` requires two pointer lookups. First it goes into memory to find the pointer to row `i`, then it goes into memory to find the datum at column `j` within that row. In contrast, `img[i * width + j]` does only one pointer lookup. Memory access in modern hardware is much more expensive than the trivial index computation.
3. **Data locality.** When filtering, you often need to look up a neighboring pixels. In the array of array style, each row of pixels is in a separate memory block, the neighbor at `i+1` could be in a totally different part of the address space. This is really hard on the cache.
4. **Indexing simplicity.** It is not often that you need to access the pixel at a given set of coordinates. For most image processing, you either iterate over all pixels in the image, or you iterate over the neighborhood of a pixel. With the array of array style, you always need to use indices. To find a neighbor, you need to compute the neighbor's indices, and dereference two pointers. In the flat array style, you only need to do a pointer addition and one dereference: if you're at index `i`, the neighbors are at `i-width`, `i+width`, `i-1`, `i+1`, etc. Most of the time you're not actually using the coordinates themselves (e.g. checking for out-of-bounds reads when accessing neighbors can often be done without knowing the coordinates of a pixel, by maintaining a matching array that marks border pixels).

   This is an important point, so I'm going to illustrate it from a different perspective. With the "prettier" `img[i][j]` syntax, you need to deal with two indices; if you want to visit all 8 neighbors of a pixel, you need to write complex code to manage these two indices. With the "ugly" `img[i * width + j]` syntax you're only dealing with a single index; if you want to visit all 8 neighbors, you just keep a list of index offsets for the 8 neighbors, and loop over the list. What looked like an advantage for the array of arrays style, actually becomes a disadvantage when you want to do more than just access one single, isolated pixel.
5. **Color images.** For the RGB case shown in the OP, it is not necessary to have three separate arrays, one can use a single array, and compute the index as follows: `img[(i * width + j) * 3 + c]`. This simplifies all the code shown, since there is now just one statement where previously there were three nearly identical ones:

```
img = (unsigned char *)malloc(ImgSize * 3);
for (int i = 0; i < ImgSize * 3; i++) {
    img[i] = fgetc(f);
}
for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Width; j++) {
        for (int c = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            img[getIndex(i,j) * 3 + c] = int(B[getIndex(i,j) * 3 + c] * num);
        }
    }
}
```

The statement

```
img[getIndex(i,j) * 3 + c] = int(B[getIndex(i,j) * 3 + c] * num);
```

can of course be simplified to

```
img[getIndex(i,j) * 3 + c] *= num;
```

but most importantly, we don't need so many loops. The data is contiguous, we can use a single loop (and this is the case for maybe 95% of things we want to do with the pixel data):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ImgSize * 3; i++) {
   img[i] *= num;
}
```

This is easier to read, easier to maintain, and it's a bit faster to boot.